# how to combine 2 or more strings in text file

Tags: c#, text-files

I've been trying to find a way to combine 2 strings from a single text file. The text file that I am reading has the following format:

`String 1

String 2

String 3`
...etc. 
Sample Code:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> getMeaningfulLines(string filename)
    {
        System.IO.StreamReader file =
          new System.IO.StreamReader(filename);
        while (!file.EndOfStream)
        {

            yield return file.ReadLine();
            yield return file.ReadLine();

            file.ReadLine();
            file.ReadLine();
            file.ReadLine();
            file.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        foreach (string line in getMeaningfulLines(@"C://Log.txt"))
        {




            string teststring = line;

            string[] parts = line.Split(' ', ',', '-', '>', '[', ']');
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();


            foreach (string h in parts)
            {
                builder.Append(h).Append(" ");

            }

            string result = builder.ToString();
            string cleanedString = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result, @"\s+", " ");
            string trimString = cleanedString.Trim();

            trimString = trimString.Remove(trimString.Length - 1);


            //Console.WriteLine(trimString);

            string[] parts2 = trimString.Split(' ');
            string quotedstring = "'" + string.Join("','", parts2) + "'";
            //Console.WriteLine(quotedstring);
            string[] parts3 = quotedstring.Split(' ');
            Console.WriteLine(quotedstring, quotedstring.Length);
            //Console.WriteLine("1) The length of '{0}' is {1}",  quotedstring, quotedstring.Length);
```

I would want to append string 2 to string 1 to have: "String1 String2". I tried using the split method and appended them using a string builder. However, this does not work because its doing the splitting and appending per line. I also cant use "." to combine them because they are not stored in variables. Does anyone know how to achieve this or an example? Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "However, this does not work because its doing the splitting and appending per line"?

Comment: Can you give a sample of your code and also explain what you mean by it not working because of splitting per line? How you are reading in the file can make a difference to what the solution is...

Comment: Sorry, I did not mention that there are a couple of fields within the strings, all of them. Ex: 'name', 'id', 'city', 'state'. So I can split these and append them back to a single string, but on a line per line basis.

Comment: How can you have multiple strings that are not stored in variables?  Your question is not clear.  You need to show us some code otherwise our answers will have to assume things that might not be true.

Comment: Definetly you should edit your question including 1) Complete example data of the text file 2) Code you are using to read the file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The text file that I am reading has the following format: 
>   String 1
>   String 2 
>   String 3 ...etc. I would want to append string 2 to string 1 to have: "String1 String2".

If you would like to append each line in your file, with a space between them, then do this:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("my_file.txt");
string result = string.Join(" ", lines);
```

If the lines of the file have structure, then you can define a class to hold this structure, e.g.:

```
class Company
{
  private string name;
  private int id; 
  private string city;
  private string state;

  public string Name { get { return name; } }
  public int Id  { get { return id; } } 
  public string City { get { return city; } }
  public string State { get { return state; } }

  public Company(string name, int id, string city, string state) 
  {
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
    this.city = city;
    this.state = state; 
  }

  public override string ToString() 
  {
    // Create a formatted string from the fields here, for example:
    return name + " " + id + " " + city + " " + state;
  }

  public static Company FromLine(string line)
  {
    // Extract the fields from a line, and post-process the fields here, for example:
    string[] tokens = line.Split(separators);
    string name = tokens[0].Trim();
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(tokens[1]);
    string city = tokens[2];
    string state = tokens[3];
    return new Company(name, id, city, state);
  }
}
```

This class can be used to extract the fields of each line, format them, and append these formatted strings:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("my_file.txt");
List<Company> companies = new List<Company>();
foreach (string line in lines)
  companies.Add(Company.FromLine(line));
string result = string.Join(" ", companies);
```

You can even specify which items to append, just modify the last line e.g. like this:

```
string result = string.Join(" ", companies.Where(company => company.Id > 10));
```

Comment: thanks for your response, I will give it a try and see how it works.

Answer (score 1):

The following should do what you want but may not be suitable depending on the size of the file, etc. which is why it is important to give context for that sort of thing. This is the quickest way I can think of though.

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
string joinedString = String.Format("{0} {1}", lines[0], lines[1]);
```